# Using Nuxt and TailwindCSS how to make full height

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using nuxt and tailwindcss. How can I make it so my sidebar's min-height fills the available space? for some reason the __nuxt element appears to be breaking everything from working. How do i work around this?

My layout file is...
**main.vue**

```
<template>
    <nav-bar />
    <slot />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
useHead({
    htmlAttrs: {
        class: "h-full bg-gray-50",
    },
    bodyAttrs: {
        class: "h-full",
    },
});
</script>
```

**index.vue**

```
<template>
     <div class="bg-red-100 m-h-full">
        <div v-for="index in 10" v-bind:key="index">
            here
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script setup lang="ts">

definePageMeta({
  layout: "main",
});

</script>
```

I get this which you can see the red does not extend to fill the height.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Experiencing the same problem right now

Answer (score 1):

As you already said in your question, you'd have to apply the classes to every parent element, including the wrapper `div` for the Nuxt app. I don't know if there is something like a hook to access this element, but what I'd do in your situation is simply adding this to my CSS somewhere:

```css
#__nuxt {
  @apply h-full;
}
```

In case you didn't know, the `@apply` directive is tailwind's way of using their classes inside CSS.

Edit: The wrapper element has an ID, not a class.

Answer (score 0):

`h-full` and `m-h-full` refer to the height of the parent.
you probably have to add `m-h-full` to all ancestor elements up to `<html>`

The [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) say:

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
> generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
> block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
> height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
> computes to auto. A percentage height on the root element is relative
> to the initial containing block.

also consider [viewport height](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height#viewport-height), sometimes it is a better fit.

Comment: Based on previous experiences with Chrome I think that the rule should also go up to the html element